# Group by query in single row with max count in SQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to the database.I have requirement to show data in group by query with case statement and max of the result from the database.

Below are the table data from mysql db that i used.

1. `create table department (deptid int not null auto_increment,deptname varchar(20) not null,primary key ( deptid));`

   DEPARTMENT table data:

   ```
   deptid | deptname
   -------+---------
   1      | IT      
   2      | HR      
   3      | ADMIN
   ```
2. Customer table creation script.

   ```
   create table customer (
       custid int not null auto_increment,
       custname varchar(20) not null,
       recordkey int,
       deptid int,
       primary key (custid),
       foreign key (deptid) references Department(deptid)
   );
   ```

   Customer table data:

   ```
   custid | custname | recordkey | deptid 
   -------+----------+-----------+-------
   1      | A        | 1         | 1
   2      | B        | 1         | 2
   3      | C        | 1         | 1
   -------+----------+-----------+--------
   ```
3. Below I tried using the `group by` query result.

   ```
   select c.recordkey,count(d.deptid),d.deptname from department d join
       customer c on d.deptid=c.deptid
       group by c.recordkey,d.deptid,d.deptname;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   recordkey | count(d.deptid) | deptname 
   ----------+-----------------+---------           
   1         | 2               | IT
   1         | 1               | HR
   ```
4. I also tried with case statement:

   ```
   select c.recordkey,d.deptname,
       case when d.deptname='IT' then count(d.dept name)
       else 0 end as itcount,
       case when d.deptname='HR' then count(d.deptname)
       else 0 end as hrcount from department d
       join customer c on d.deptid=c.deptid
       group by c.recordkey,d.deptname;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   recordkey | deptname | itcount | hrcount
   ----------+----------+---------+--------
   1         | HR       | 0       | 1
   1         | IT       | 2       | 0
   ```

   Here as per the requirement the result must be single line.
5. But final result should be `deptid` with their `count` and `max` of from the count. For example IT department have max records.

   ```
   recordkey | itdeptid | itdeptname | itocunt | hrdeptid | hrdeptname | hrcount | admindeptid | admindeptname | admincount | max of (itocunt hrcount admincount)
   ----------+----------+------------+---------+----------+------------+---------+-------------+---------------+------------+------------------------------------
   1         | 1        | IT         | 2       | 2        | HR         | 1       | 3           | ADMIN         | 0          | 2
   ```

It would be great if anyone had any suggestions.

Comment: You need to format this. If you don't know how, read the intro posts for this site. If you don't know where they are, look around. Then edit your tags, too - it is unlikely that, new as you are to database, you are using MySQL **and** SQL Server **and** Oracle, all at once.

Comment: Search for mysql pivot.